# Sublime Text custom plugin : change style, tab color or back-ground color

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext3

Sometimes, I work directly on production file (I know it's very ugly and provides several risks, but at the moment, I have no choice). I want a way to easly recognize that I work on production file. I can work on file_name because production files are in production folder (or equivalent). So I began a Sublime Text plugin to change the tab background or code background in another color.

I'm able te display style informations but I don't know how to change this style...

Early stage plugin :

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
class TestStCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if "production" in str(self.view.file_name()):
            print("===== self.view.style() =====")
            print(self.view.style())
```

Output of plugin :

```
===== self.view.style() =====
{'active_guide': '#7a4815', 'find_highlight': '#ffe894', 'inactive_selection_foreground': '#f8f8f2', 'background': '#282923', 'selection_foreground': '#f8f8f2', 'highlight': '#c4c4bd', 'selection': '#48473d', 'rulers': '#5c5c56', 'selection_border': '#212117', 'shadow': '#141411', 'accent': '#67d8ef', 'misspelling': '#f92472', 'gutter': '#282923', 'guide': '#474842', 'stack_guide': '#7a4815', 'line_highlight': '#3e3d32', 'foreground': '#f8f8f2', 'gutter_foreground': '#90908a', 'minimap_border': '#90908a', 'caret': '#f8f8f1', 'invisibles': '#70716b', 'inactive_selection': '#383830', 'find_highlight_foreground': '#000000'}
```

Can you give me a way to modifiy theme (or color) programmatically in Sublime Text plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sublime the color of a file tab always follows the color of the background of the file, and the only thing that can change that is the `color_scheme` setting.

In particular, even though the API allows you to see the colors that are in use for a particular style such as you pointed out in your question, there's no direct analogue for an API function to alter one of those styles directly.

The general tactic would then be to respond to the information that a file is a production file by changing the `color_scheme` setting for that file to something else to apply the color changes you want.

This could be done manually via a command as you outlined in your question or you could use an `EventListener` to monitor file events to perform the checks for you so that the color change is seamless, or some combination thereof.

An example of such a plugin would be this:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

# A global list of potential path fragments that indicate that a file is a
# production file.
_prod_paths = ["/production/", "/prod/"]

# The color scheme to apply to files that are production files.
#
# If the color scheme you use is a `tmTheme` format, the value here needs to
# be a full package resource path. For sublime-color-scheme, only the name of
# the file should be used.
_prod_scheme = "Monokai-Production.sublime-color-scheme"
# _prod_scheme = "Packages/Color Scheme - Legacy/Blackboard.tmTheme"

class ProductionEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """
    Listen for files to be loaded or saved and alter their color scheme if
    any of the _production_path path fragments appear in their paths.
    """
    def alter_color_scheme(self, view):
        if view.file_name():
            # Get the current color scheme and an indication if this file
            # contains a production path fragment,.
            scheme = view.settings().get("color_scheme")
            is_prod = any(p for p in _prod_paths if p in view.file_name())

            # If this file is a production file and the color scheme is not the
            # production scheme, change it now.
            if is_prod and scheme != _prod_scheme:
                view.settings().set("color_scheme", _prod_scheme)

            # If the file is not production but has the production color scheme
            # remove our custom setting; this can happen if the path has
            # changed, for example.
            if not is_prod and scheme == _prod_scheme:
                view.settings().erase("color_scheme")

    # Use our method to handle file loads and saves
    on_load = on_post_save = alter_color_scheme
```

Each view has it's own local `settings` object that inherits the default settings but also allows you to provide per-view settings. Here the plugin applies a `color_scheme` setting that overrides the inherited version when it detects that a file contains a production path segment, and erases that custom setting (reverting to the inherited version) if you `Save As` the file to a name that's no longer a production path.

The remaining piece of the puzzle is how you determine what color scheme you want to use here. For the example above I manually created a duplicate of the `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme` that ships with Sublime and modified the `background` property to alter the displayed color a bit.

Alternatively you could choose some other color scheme to use as the one for production instead, or even generate a `sublime-color-scheme` on the fly.

In such a case you would probably want to use `sublime.load_resource()` and `sublime.decode_value()` to load and decode a `sublime-color-scheme` into a JSON object, then manipulate the colors and save the file as a new `sublime-color-scheme` into your `User` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awesome answer... It's very detailed ! Perfect ! I take this opportunity to thanks you for overrideAudit ! It's great.